# How to structure my little python framework

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I wrote a simple set of python3 files for emulating a small set of mongodb features on a 32 bit platform. I fired up PyCharm and put together a directory that looked like:

```
minu/
    client.py
    database.py
    collection.py
    test_client.py
    test_database.py
    test_client.py
```

My imports are simple. For example, `client.py` has the following at the top:

```
from collection import Collection
```

Basically, client has a Client class, collection has a Collection class, and database has a Database class. Not too tough.

As long as I `cd` into the `minu` directory, I can fire up a python3 interpreter and do things like:

```
>>> from client import Client
>>> c = Client(pathstring='something')
```

And everything just works. I can run the test_files as well, which use the same sorts of imports.

I'd like to modularize this, so I can use it another project by just dropping the minu directory alongside my application's .py files and just have everything work. When I do this though, and am running python3 from another directory, the local imports don't work. I placed an empty **init**.py in the minu directory. That made it so I could `import minu`. But the others broke. I tried using things like `from .collection import Collection` (added the dot), but then I can't run things in the original directory anymore, like I could before. What is the simple/right way to do this?

*I have looked around a bit with Dr. Google, but none of the examples really clarify it well, feel free to point out the one I missed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this file `...minu/__init__.py` import the submodules you wish to expose externally.

If the `__init__.py` file contains the following lines, and the `client.py` file has a variable `foo`.

```
import client
import collection
import database
```

Then from above the minu directory, the following will work:

```
from minu.client import foo
```